# How to add a symbol after every word in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, loops, while-loop

So my code currently only puts -boink or -bork after the entire string once the conditions are met but I want it so that after every single word the terms get added based on whether or not it satisfies the conditions of being either greater or less than five characters.
For example "My-boink name-boinkk is-boink Emmanuel-bork"

```
function myFunctionOne(input1, input2) {

var prompt1 = prompt("Please enter 1, 2, 3, or Exit").toLowerCase();
var prompt2 = input2;

if (prompt1 == 1) {
prompt2 = prompt("Please enter a string");

while (prompt2.length === 0) {
  prompt2 = prompt("You need to enter something");
}

myFunctionOne(prompt1, prompt2);
}

if (prompt1 == 2) {
  if (prompt2.length > 5) {
      console.log(prompt2 + "-bork");
  }
  myFunctionOne(prompt2);
}
else {
  console.log(prompt2 + "-boink")
}

}
 myFunctionOne(1, 2, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the string into words with the split method and then loop through them using a for loop to check if they're longer than 5 characters and add 'bork' or 'boink' and then join the words again.

I could write the code for you, but I think it will be more satisfying for you to do it yourself. If you want me to write it thought let me know.

Edit
I'm going to write the code as close as what you already have as posible

```
function myFunctionOne(input1, input2) {

    var prompt1 = prompt("Please enter 1, 2, 3, or Exit").toLowerCase();
    var prompt2 = input2;

    if (prompt1 == 1) {
        prompt2 = prompt("Please enter a string");

        while (prompt2.length === 0) {
            prompt2 = prompt("You need to enter something");
        }

        myFunctionOne(prompt1, prompt2);
    }

    if (prompt1 == 2) {
        var words = prompt2.split(" "); // we separate the string into words dividing them by space into an array called words
        for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){ // we loop from 0 to the length of the array - 1 to access all positions in the array (the last position in arrays are always the length of the array - 1 because they start at 0)  
            if(words[i].length > 5){ //we check if the word in this position of the array is longer than 5 characters
                words[i] += "-bork"; //if it is we add -bork
            }else{
                words[i] += "-boink" //if it is not longer than 5 characters we add -boink
            }
        }
        console.log(words.join(" ")); //we print the array joining the elements with an space to form a string
    }

}
myFunctionOne(1, 2, null);
```

Comment: can you write it out for me please?

Comment: @JamesLin Done!! :)

Comment: thanks for the help, arrays also seem to confuse me. There's so much going on in one function is there anyway i can split everything up into multiple functions without breaking the code and still allowing the different prompts to work together

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by what's going on at the top of your code, so I'm not going to refactor the entire thing.  I'm going to provide an explanation from the time we have our string.

One approach would be to use .split(), which will return an array of string values based on what character you choose to split the string by. The reason we need to do this is because your code is currently looping through each string, rather than each word in the string.  In this instance, I'm assuming your string can't take punctuation like commas or periods. If that's the case, you want to split by empty spaces, so it would look like string.split(" ").

Then, you could use the map() array method to loop through every value in the array and perform a function on it.  Note, the map() method will return a new array, so best to save this into a new variable.

Then, you could use the .join() method, which will join the values of an array based on some value (essentially the opposite of .split()). Again, assuming no punctuation, I'd join the array with a space so that the values have a space between them, which would look like array.join(" ").

I've included some mock code below.

```
const string = prompt("Please enter your string");

const stringToArray = string.split(" ");
console.log(stringToArray);

const filteredArray = stringToArray.map((string) => {
  if (string.length > 5) {
    return string + "-bork";
  }

  return string + "-boink";
});
console.log(filteredArray);

const joinedFilteredArray = filteredArray.join(" ");
console.log(joinedFilteredArray);
```

Comment: why am i unable to change the const string to equal something like prompt("User input")

Comment: You certainly could do that. So if you were to take the code I had above and do something like const string = prompt("Please enter your string"); the code should still work.  Again, this code doesn't handle situations where there's punctuation, like commas and periods.  Are you having trouble getting it to work?

Comment: it works but only once, my google chrome console is being weird after the first one it gives me identifier string has already been declared

Comment: Ah!  It might be because you're trying to change the value of that constant.  In JavaScript, "const" stands for constant, meaning the value of that variable can't be reset.  If you're planning on using that variable name over and over, try changing "const" to "let" (e.g. let string = prompt("Please enter your string");.  Then let me know what you get.

Comment: i still get the same problem in the google chrome console, everywhere else is fine but for some reason it doesn't work more than once in the console

Comment: Without seeing your code it's tough to help. I've included an updated part of your code where you're trying to loop, add boink or bork, then log the sentence.  Try replacing your final if/else statement with that.

`if(prompt1 == 2) {
    var splitString = prompt2.split(" ");
    var mappedArray = splitString.map(function(word) {
        if (word.length > 5) {
            return word + "-bork";
        }

        return word + "-boink";
    });
}

console.log(mappedArray.join(" "));`